# An integral problem?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How do you integrate $e^{e^x}$? I was able to get it down to du/(ln u) but I wasn't able to go further. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not Calculus AB level.  This antiderivative is "not elementary" in the technical meaning of that term.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function

**added**

Maple says
$$
\int \!{{\rm e}^{{{\rm e}^{x}}}}{dx}=-{\rm Ei}_1 \left(-{{\rm e}^{x}}
 \right) 
$$
where this "exponential integral" function is
$$
\mathrm{Ei}_1(z) = \int_1^\infty\frac{e^{-tz}}{t}\;dt
$$

Comment: Then could you provide a non-elementary solution? I also have a friend who is interested in this.

Comment: This is related to one of the "non-elementary" functions which is _defined_ by its integral, called the exponential integral Ei(x).  Here's the result for $ \  a^{a^x} \ $ : http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+a%5E%28a%5Ex%29  [Sorry... should have figured there'd be more answers coming...]

Comment: It's ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int e^{e^x}dx$$
Substitute $u = e^x$.  Then $du = e^x dx$

$$\int \frac{e^u}{u} du = \operatorname{Ei}(u) + C = \operatorname{Ei}(e^x) + C$$

Where $\operatorname{Ei}$ denotes the Exponential integral $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{e^t}{t} dt$.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral